# Test Access to window.opener.document

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Is there a way to test your access to window.opener.document without using a try catch block?

Thanks, Jamie

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with a try/catch, but I'm curious whether there is some other trick.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe there is any ‘look before you leap’ way to determine whether a `WindowProxy` instance gives you full or restricted access. All you can do is try to access a potentially-restricted property and catch the SECURITY_ERR.